# Is there a good website where I can learn about Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, resource-request, ddpg

Is there a good website where I can learn about Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient?

Answer (score 2):

Spinning Up by Open Ai.

Be sure to read up Part 3 (Intro to Policy Optimisation) before you move on to : https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/ddpg.html

Comment: To know the difference, I would write out the algorithms or go through implementations in detail.